# Use Super+C/V for copy-pasting in Emacs

Tags: shortcut-keys, latex, emacs

In Emacs I activated the option to use CUA keys for copy/cut-pasting with C-c/C-x/C-v. However sometimes it creates a problem when using Latex/Auctex key shortcuts, because it "eats" the first C-c or C-x. To explain myself better, assume I want to comment out some lines in Tex. So I select them and then hit C-c ;  However the result is that it copies the selected region, deselects the region and types ";" in the beginning of the region.

Is there a way to setup Emacs so as to use Super-c/Super-x/Super-v for copying, cutting and pasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your own keybindings using an `init.el` file inside your `.emacs.d`. Just copy and paste the following code in your startup script:

```
(define-key global-map [?\s-x] 'kill-region)
(define-key global-map [?\s-c] 'kill-ring-save)
(define-key global-map [?\s-v] 'yank)
```

If you don't know the names of the commands executed by a key sequence, you can discover using `C-h k` and then pressing the key binding you want to know about. Then you just use the `define-key` to create new keybindings for this command.

You can also unmap using `global-unset-key`. Make sure your key bindings don't conflict with the operating system.

More on this:

- [Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs)

Comment: Thanks, works as it is expected! Although I put it in my .emacs file. I also added command `(define-key global-map [?\s-z] 'undo)` for undoing.